# Open JFrame from JDialog and it shows on top of JDialog

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jdialog

This is the scenario,
My `JFrame` has a button  it will open a `JDialog` when click it and it is a model dialog.
`JDialog` has another button and i want to open another `JFrmae` open when click it.

Result : another `Jframe` open but it will not come to the top.It shows under the dialog.I want to open the 2nd `JFrame` on top of that dialog.

can use `secondFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);` but i don't have control to close it or move it.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class FrameTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame firstFrame = new JFrame("My 1st Frame");
        JButton button = new JButton("Frame Click");

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
                dialog.setSize(100, 100);
                dialog.setModal(true);
                JButton button1 = new JButton("Dialog Click");

                button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        JFrame secondFrame = new JFrame("My 2nd Frame");
                        secondFrame.setVisible(true);
                        secondFrame.setSize(400, 200);
                        secondFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        secondFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                     }
                });

                dialog.add(button1);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        firstFrame.add(button);
        firstFrame.setVisible(true);
        firstFrame.setSize(400, 200);
        firstFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: look into modal types. Also, have you considered simply not using a jdialog and just using a frame instead? You have significantly more control over a frame (in my opinion).

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/2587435). See the accepted answer for some better solutions.

Comment: Do you know what `dialog.setModal(true);` means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> JDialog has another button and i want to open another JFrmae open when
>   click it.

Don't do that. A tipical Swing application has a single main `JFrame` and several `JDialog`s. See this topic [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

> Result : another Jframe open but it will not come to the top.It shows
>   under the dialog.I want to open the 2nd JFrame on top of that dialog.

Of course it does because the dialog is modal.

> can use secondFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true); but i don't have control to
>   close it or move it.

It won't solve anything because the problem has to do with modality in dialogs. See this article: [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html) to understand how modality works. There's an explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22041971/1795530) too.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
secondFrame.setModalExclusionType(ModalExclusionType.APPLICATION_EXCLUDE);
```

It worked for me in the same situation.